# Is it possible to create a Full Screen Intent for Android via FCM?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm working on an Android app that receives high priority emergency notifications and I'm looking to create the closest parity I can with iOS's critical alerts.  I found this [Android Developer Article](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive) that mentions using `setFullScreenIntent` as an extra measure to get the user's attention.

I am using FCM to push these notifications but I don't see any corresponding configuration for a "full screen intent" in the [AndroidConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidconfig) section.

Am I missing something or is it not possible to use this feature for notifications sent via FCM?  If not possible, is it possible it will be added to the API in the future, and if so are such enhancements/updates tracked somewhere I can access?

Thank you.

Comment: What stops you from sending the additional parameter in the `data` json object, e.g.  `isFullScreen: true`, and handle this property on the client side?

Comment: @Sergey nothing is stopping me from doing that, however, ideally I'm looking for a solution that will be handled by the Android Notification System for cases when the app is not running and therefor no application code is executed for me to do something with that additional parameter.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you out. If so, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer  If you still have questions, feel free to ask 

Answer (score 0):

Alright you can check here `firebase_messaging: ^11.3.0`

Since update [8.0.0-dev.1](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/changelog#800-dev1) we can get onBackgroundMessage by default without any need for these installation process

for better reference check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554157/how-to-get-a-full-screen-notification-from-fcm#:%7E:text=Alright.,background%20or%20terminated.)